# Discovery procedure of Bluetooth GATT services

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Following the model of permissions of GATT characteristics (stated [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html)), I'm wondering if it is possible for a GATT server to hide one or several of its services to an unauthenticated or unauthorized GATT client ?

If it is possible, do you have some example of implementation or framework that allow to configure GATT services to be undiscoverable when the client is not authenticated ?

Comment: Yes this is possible and you can do this by setting the characteristic property when creating the GATT server services/characteristics. Which implementation/stack do you want the example in? Or any implementation should do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From what I've understood it is possible to set permissions only on characteristics, not on services (as stated in the example of the [espressif-idf](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/gatt_security_server/tutorial/Gatt_Security_Server_Example_Walkthrough.md) framework). What I want to do is to restrict the discovery of a service (not a value of a characteristic) through a permission that hides the service during the discovery procedure until the client is authenticated. Is it possible to do this ?